# How to replace specific values in a oracle database column?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I am looking to replace values in a particular column. For example the following column values

```
column name
----------
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test12
```

should be (replacing `est1` with `rest1`)

```
column name
----------
Trest1
Test2
Test3
Trest12
```

Comment: I looked at the search results and found ones that use replace to get values from a dual table. I am looking to update the table as opposed to get values.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php):

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.column, 'est1', 'rest1')
  FROM MY_TABLE t
```

If you want to update the values in the table, use:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE t
   SET column = REPLACE(t.column, 'est1', 'rest1')
```

Comment: In Oracle this should be UPDATE t, not UPDATE TABLE t.

Comment: @Tom Presumably 'TABLE' is used here as the fictional table name (and 't' is the alias). The select statement is also getting values from a similarly named fictional table.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to update the value in a particular table:

```
UPDATE TABLE-NAME SET COLUMN-NAME = REPLACE(TABLE-NAME.COLUMN-NAME, 'STRING-TO-REPLACE', 'REPLACEMENT-STRING');
```

where

```
  TABLE-NAME         - The name of the table being updated
  COLUMN-NAME        - The name of the column being updated
  STRING-TO-REPLACE  - The value to replace
  REPLACEMENT-STRING - The replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there is the concept of schema name, so try using this

```
update schemname.tablename t
set t.columnname = replace(t.columnname, t.oldvalue, t.newvalue);
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm using Version 4.0.2.15 with Build 15.21

For me I needed this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name,"search str","replace str");
```

Putting `t.column_name` in the first argument of `replace` did not work.