# Replace Spaces in Telephone Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have a telephone number column which has spaces in between the numbers.

For example:

```
07595 8832 36
0161 88143 09
016188121 1 1
0 7 585 99 21 2 2
```

How do I replaces the spaces and get the number all together?

Example:

```
07595 8832 36

07595883236 (like this)
```

The table name is called `[dbo].[NumberChecker3]`

And the column in the database is called `Telephone`

Comment: I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621778/how-to-replace-a-character-from-a-string-in-sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814548/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-sql-server-table-column)

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE (phone_number, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[NumberChecker3] SET telephone = REPLACE (telephone , ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select replace(replace( rtrim(replace(Telephone,char(160),'')) , char(9),''), ' ','')
from [dbo].[NumberChecker3]
```

if work fine for you then:

```
update [dbo].[NumberChecker3]
set Telephone = replace(replace( rtrim(replace(Telephone,char(160),'')) , char(9),''), ' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[NumberChecker3] SET [Telephone] = REPLACE (Telephone , ' ', '')
```

this is for the update or if you just need to get the number without space then try this

```
Declare @number nvarchar(10);
select @number = REPLACE (Telephone , ' ', '') From [dbo].[NumberChecker3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the REPLACE method of sql server from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

like this

```
REPLACE(phone_number,' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this aslo

```
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX) =  '07595 8832 36'
select REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@XML)),' ','')
```

Comment: explain why you need to trim when replacing the spaces