# Replace a specific character in column names

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have two fields :

```
-name
-address
```

How to change a specific letter? For example: `'a'` changed to `'o'` so the field names become:

```
-nome
-oddress
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443156/how-to-replace-specific-values-in-a-oracle-database-column) but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually **renaming** a column, or updating data in a column?

Comment: rename the column but not the whole, just a specific letter

Comment: You cannot issue a command that changes one letter of a column name (and why would you wish to?), you have to rename the column - see @kevinsky's answer for how.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Thank you for responding , I got this question from college :) i think he was wrong about this question

Comment: It would be more likely that he meant you to change the values in the columns - e.g. using the `translate` function

Comment: Renaming column names is possible, though I think it is a rather constructed use case ;) see solution below ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script replaces all `A`'s in all column names of all tables belonging to owner `SCOTT` by `O`'s:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR alters IS
  SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' RENAME COLUMN ' || 
          column_name ||' TO ' || REPLACE (column_name, 'A', 'O') AS statement
    FROM dba_tab_columns
   WHERE owner = 'SCOTT'
     AND column_name LIKE '%A%';
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN alters LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.statement;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You need `SELECT` rights on table `dba_tab_columns`. Note that it is case-sensitive.

Have a lot of fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

does this do what you want?

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

Comment: rename the column but not the whole, just a specific letter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need where I had to replace " " with "*" in more than a thousand field. I did it with Excel where I made concatenation in order to get a thousand different request like :
alter table a rename column "a134*    60 000" to "a134_____60_000";
Not very sexy... but solved in a couple of minutes!