# Update query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I need to update all gmail.com email id in the table emails to yahoo.com. I have this below query which doesn't works. Can someone help?

```
update emails
set email = (select CONCAT(email, '@yahoo.com ') "email"
from emails )
where email like '%@gmail.com%'
```

---

Comment: Please show a bit of sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Its a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443156/how-to-replace-specific-values-in-a-oracle-database-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
    update emails
    set email = REPLACE(email,'@gmail.com','@yahoo.com')
    where email like '%@gmail.com%'
```