# How to replace a value in a comma separated string column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace all the occurrences of 4 with the number 2 in a string column of a table.
This is a hardcoded value of 2 which replaces all occurrences of the number 4 in a Oracle table. The LOBS column is a VARCHAR column

| ID | LOBS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,4,6,7,8 |
| 2 | 1,5,6,7,9,4 |
| 3 | 3,5,7,8,11,4 |

New Table

| ID | LOBS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,6,7,8 |
| 2 | 1,5,6,7,9,2 |
| 3 | 3,5,7,8,11,2 |

Comment: Which is your DBMS product? Oracle or Mysql? BTW you need a simple REPLACE function.

Comment: Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace specific values in a oracle database column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443156/how-to-replace-specific-values-in-a-oracle-database-column)

Comment: @IshaanKanwar Oracle SQL Developer is a client application that connects to many databases; it is **NOT** a database. Please [edit] your question to add the correct tag for the database that you are connecting to through SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use simple (quick) string functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(','||lobs||',', ',4,', ',2,'))
         AS updated_lobs
FROM   table_name;
```

Or (slower) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(lobs,'(^|,)4(,|$)','\12\2') AS updated_lobs
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, LOBS) AS
SELECT 1, '1,4,64,7,8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '4,1,5,64,7,9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '3,5,64,8,11,4' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | UPDATED_LOBS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1,2,64,7,8 |
> | 2 | 2,1,5,64,7,9 |
> | 3 | 3,5,64,8,11,2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4fae98e42a21e7645a46247a5db4a3d)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple REPLACE function Oracle will work for you -

```
SELECT REPLACE(LOBS, '4', '2')
  FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Would this also change 14 to 12?

Comment: This does not work as it would replace 14->12

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEP_REPLACE

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   ID INTEGER,
>   LOBS VARCHAR2(12)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (ID, LOBS)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1,2,6,7,8');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (ID, LOBS)
> VALUES
>   ('2', '2,6,7,8,9');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
>   (ID, LOBS)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '1,5,6,7,9,2');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
>   (ID, LOBS)
> VALUES
>   ('4', '3,5,7,8,11,2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
>        REGEXP_REPLACE(
>        REGEXP_REPLACE(LOBS,'^2,','4,')
>        ,'(,2,)',',4,'),',2$',',4') FROM table1
>        WHERE 1= 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(LOBS,'^2,','4,'),'(,2,)',',4,'),',2$',',4') |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 1,4,6,7,8                                                                                |
> | 4,6,7,8,9                                                                                |
> | 1,5,6,7,9,4                                                                              |
> | 3,5,7,8,11,4                                                                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=124957fd16c36f4e17e7eead4672bc6f)*